# Is it bad practice to use the entire map image as a tilemap?

Tags: tilemap, maps, png

I made a map in photoshop which I want to use as a map in my game. The question is should I try to cut it up to pieces, or is it bad (performance wise) if I use  the way I made it. The picture itself is really specific without any repeatable part so I'm not sure if I can cut it up to smaller parts.

*I'm kinda new to game developement, so pls forgive me if I asked something stupid here.*

Comment: If your map isn't suited to tiles, why would you cut it into tiles? Is there some constraint of your pipeline that needs to work in tiles, or are you experiencing hardware limitations or performance problems from using the image whole?

Answer (score 1):

In general you want all your textures to be big and few, usually devs, when they have multiple small sprites for a game, they combine them to one single texture ([Texture Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas)), so I'd recommend to have your map in one texture.

However, it kinda depends on how big the map is. Obviously if you have a giant map of a huge open world, and you can only explore a tiny fraction of it, you don't want all of that constantly in memory. In this case, you'd probably need to separate it and load each one dynamically. Where do you draw the line of how big a map should be to do that? that's up to you to decide, depending what platforms you want to support, with OpenGL for example, max texture size can be about 2048 or 4096 or something else (depending on the hardware), if you target phones, I wouldn't be surprised if it was less than that.

If your game is simply multiple regular-sized "stages" or something like that, it's better loading the whole stage map at once, if it's an open world, you have to find a way to do it dynamically (one of the struggles of making an open world game).